# How to add a read only group permission to a folder that already has a default group, and have it inherited for all newly created files & folders?

Tags: permissions, freebsd, acl

In Windows this is easy.  I never fully figured out Linux permissions, I have a directory such as this:

**/Photos**

The current ACL permissions are as follows:

```
owner: root - full access
group: photos -full access
everyone: no access
```

the **photos** group currently has full access.  But I would like to add an additional group that have read only access, called **readOnlyPhotos**, without enabling read access to "everyone".

That is, I want that folder to be inaccessible to anyone except for people who are either in **photos** group (who get full access) or **readOnlyPhotos** group (who get read only access).  Also any new files and folders that get created in the **/Photos** folder should inherit these default permissions.

How can I configure the permissions on the **/Photos** folder to achieve this effect?

Comment: Try `man setfacl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using traditional Unix permissions, you'll have to use [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), that's Access Control Lists. Traditional Unix permissions do not accommodate more than 1 group per file/directory. Window's uses something similar. The commands to apply ACLs are called `setfacl` and `getfacl`.

See my answer on this Q&A titled: [Getting new files to inherit group permissions on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux/115632#115632) for an example that's similar to what you're looking for.