# Can one directory be owned by two groups?

Tags: permissions, files, group

Can one directory be owned by two groups (RHEL 6.2)?

I have created one directory:    `mkdir /opt/shared`, then I created two groups: `groupadd sales` `groupadd marketing`

I added manually to each of these groups 21 users, then I changed the ownership
`chown root:sales /opt/shared` and `chown root:marketing /opt/shared`.

Then I changed the unmask `chmod 2775 /opt/shared`

The problem is, only group `marketing` have permission to `rwx`.

Comment: Related to many Q&A's on the site. Here's one for starters: [How to add a read only group permission to a folder that already has a default group, and have it inherited for all newly created files & folders?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127489/how-to-add-a-read-only-group-permission-to-a-folder-that-already-has-a-default-g/127495#127495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory (like everything else) can only have one group (the "ACL_GROUP_OBJ" in ACL terminology). But via ACL (`setfacl`) you can define permissions for other groups, too. Even (via default ACLs) for newly created objects in the directory.