# How to manage permissions correctly when adding a new package to a reprepro repo

Tags: permissions, reprepro

I've setup a local repo with reprepro, accessible via a local web server. Thus every file and dir in its file sub-tree owns to `www-data:www-data`. The problem is that every time I add a new package I need to use sudo, that makes all the permissions of the files involved to change, and every time I have to fix this by hand.

Any clue how can I avoid this? Maybe using a sticky bit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear why `sudo` is changing your file permissions. Can you provide an example? In any case, `acl` is often an option if you want to "force" permissions. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115632/4671. If you give more details, I may be able to offer a more detailed response.

Comment: Because acting as root changes the permission from `www-data` to `root` with its umask, and it brokes the whole mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `sudo` you want to run commands as `www-data` instead of `root`:

```
sudo -u www-data ...
```

That way the ownership of your repository won’t change.

Comment: It works, I tried before with: `su www-data -c 'reprepro etc... ` but it returned this error: `This account is currently not available`