# Files inside folder change their permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I am struggling with the following problem.
I have read the following guide: [Getting new files to inherit group permissions on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux)
Yet, this has not helped me.

(pgcluu is a postgresql cluster monitoring program)

I am using `Debian server`

I have a folder  `/var/www/pgcluu`

Inside that folder i have
`stats` `reports` folders.
I have changed `stats` folder permission and ownership over to postgres.
`chmod -R postgres:postgres /var/www/pgcluu` (so the full folder is owner by postgres)

pgCluu on the other hand is collecting data and is generating files inside `stats` folder.
Looking something like.
`/var/www/pgcluu/stat/2018/04/04/09` 
basically `/year/month/day/hour/`
Inside the `hour` folder i have files like

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres    44 Apr  4 10:20 pg_stat_connections.csv
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres   940 Apr  4 10:20 pg_stat_database_conflicts.csv
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres  2479 Apr  4 10:20 pg_stat_database.csv
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres     1 Apr  4 10:20 pg_stat_replication.csv
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres     0 Apr  4 10:20 pg_stat_statements.csv
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres    88 Apr  4 10:20 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres 21425 Apr  4 10:20 postgresql.conf
-rw-r-----+ 1 postgres postgres 70009 Apr  4 10:20 sysinfo.txt
```

This is just an example, there are alot of more files.

The files are generated by `pgcluu_collectd` every minute (u can change it)
But they need to be rewritten, therefor it needs to have `rw- rw- ---` permissions to do it. (Owner and group must have read and write on the files)
Each time i change it myself, pgcluu_collectd makes the files with `rw- r-- ---` permissions again.

Therefor,  is there a away that the files would inherit permissions from the folder `/var/www/pgcluu/stats`

```
root@p12: getfacl /var/www/pgcluu/stats/

# file: var/www/pgcluu/stats/
# owner: postgres
# group: postgres
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:postgres:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

and on the file

```
root@p12:getfacl /var/www/pgcluu/stats/2018/04/04/10/pg_hba.conf 
# file: var/www/pgcluu/stats/2018/04/04/10/pg_hba.conf
# owner: postgres
# group: postgres
user::rw-
group::r-x          #effective:r--
group:postgres:r-x      #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

Comment: The `+` sign at the end of the permissions indicates that ACLs are in use. Please run `getfacl /var/www/pgcluu/stats` and add (edit) it to your original question. It might be useful to run `getfacl` on one of the files generated by pgCluu also (since all of these seem to have similar permissions, just pick one).

Comment: I edited my post. I tried the post above with ACLs but did not really get it how i wanted it to be. ( i can always delete the folder and start again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getfacl` output for the directory explains it.
The fourth line:

```
# flags: -s-
```

indicates the directory has the `setgid` bit set, so all files generated within it will get the same group this directory has. New sub-directories will inherit both the group and the `setgid` bit. This is not related to ACLs at all; this is just a basic `chmod 2755`.

At the end of the listing, there are several lines marked with the `default` keyword:

```
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:postgres:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::---
```

These specify with more detail the permissions any new files or sub-directories will get. In this case, it enforces r-x group permissions to the standard POSIX group owner, and adds explicit r-x permissions for the `postgres` group whether the creator belongs to that group or not. If you need the files to have group write access, these need to be changed.

Try this:

```
setfacl -m g::rwX,d:g::rwX,d:g:postgres:rwX /var/www/pgcluu/stats
```

With Linux `setfacl`, the `mask` part of the ACL should be automatically updated to include write access. (With a more strict-POSIX system you would have to add `d:m:rwx` to the ACL specification to explicitly adjust the ACL mask.)

The upper-case X indicates "execute permission, but only for directories, and also for files that already have an execute permission for someone."

If the directory (and any new files you create in it) has the permissions you want after this modification, you might consider adding the `-R` option to make the change recursively to all files and directories under `/var/www/pgcluu/stats`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped my permissions problem. Seems like my issue is related with pgCluu software itself. It is still not working whilst it has all the permissions to generate new data.

Comment: How would you use that `d:m:rwx` in your script you mentioned?

Comment: That would be `setfacl -m g::rwX,d:g::rwX,d:g:postgres:rwX,d:m:rwx <file or dir>`.