# new files have different permissions

Tags: permissions

I have a folder I'm sharing with another user in a linux centos 7 box. even though I've set the permissions for the full folder to 777 it still locks new files created by the other user.

the folder is /data folder. How do I tell linux, "all files currently in /data and every file ever created in /data should always and forever be completely available for anyone to do anything they want to"?

I've already tried a few things but I'm new to linux so I don't really understand. I know how to use chmod to change permissions but it seems those changes don't persist on new files even if I make those changes to the directory itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting new files to inherit group permissions on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission of files that you create is defined by the umask of a user during creation-time. You can see my umask by:

```
ljm[~]$ umask
0022
```

A user can set his umask with:

```
umask 0000
```

(This effectively makes every file readable and writable by everyone; don't do this)

In general, the permissions are determined by the owner of the file. This is called discretionary access controll. As owner, you can do:

```
chmod a+rw /data/file
```

If you are root on the system, you can do this for all files. You might even put a line in crontab for root that runs `chmod -R a+rw /data` every minute or so.

But, unless you are very good friends with all the other possible users of the computer (even all the passer-by's or hackers that may gain access to your system), don't do this.  A solution in a security-relaxed environment might be:

- create a group for access to `/data`; `chown root.datagrp /data`
- make the directory 3777 (chmod 1777 /data). In this way users can delete their own file. but not others and all the files will be of the group `datagep`
- set umask for all users on 0002  and add the users to the `datagrp`

And really read-up on Unix/linux permissions; search for "unix file permissions umask explained" in google.