# How to set the default group, file permissions, and folder permissions, for an ext4 mount point?

Tags: debian, permissions, ext4, fstab

I have an `ext4` disk/partition on my machine and I want to make it so, **by default**:

- All files/folders have the group set to `groupA`
- All files have:

  - **user** permissions `rw`
  - **group** permissions `rw` so folks in `groupA` can read and edit files
  - no **other** permissions
- All folders have:

  - **user** permissions `rwx`
  - **group** permissions `rwx` so folks in `groupA` can list folders and create new files/folders in them
  - no **other** permissions

I thought I could do this with `umask` and `gid` in `/etc/fstab` but `ext4` file systems do not support them.

If this matters, this is a fresh install of Debian.

I am not using ACLs and would prefer not to if possible.

Comment: Does changing permissions on the mount point (after the partition is mounted) give you what you need?

Comment: Yes. I can do it manually but I am trying to find a way to do this automatically for all files/folders created.

Comment: Does this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux

Comment: Not possible without ACLs.

Comment: Besides ACLs this is not managed by the file system at all.  The mount options you have found are not defaults they are used for filesystems that don't have permissions at all like FAT32.  Besides ACLs this is only controlled by the user process.  So ACLs are you own option. See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315/20140

Comment: @ajgringo619 No, it doesn't. Not completely. It doesn't address the default file permissions part.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thanks! I will check out ACLs.